# Обязательное поле для заполнения

Tags: html, form

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать поле в веб-форме обязательным для заполнения?

Comment: <input type="text" name="fld1" required />

Comment: `required` работает только при поддержке html5

лучше организовать проверку обязательного поля дополнительно

Comment: Через JavaScript?

Comment: первичную проверку можно делать на `JavaScript`

но если данные важные, необходимо перепроверять на сервере (`php`)

Comment: На сервере ВСЕГДА нужно перепроверять.

Answer (score 3):

Как было сказано в комментариях в хтмл5 действительно есть атрибут required, но на данный момент он работает некорректно в большинстве браузеров.

Советую реализовать проверку с помощью javascript (в целях безопасности обязательно проверять на стороне сервера). [**В интернете**](https://www.google.com.ua/#hl=ru&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&pq=jquery%20form%20validation&cp=10&gs_id=8h&xhr=t&q=javascript+form+validation&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=javascript+form+validation&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f39cb589558740e1&biw=1358&bih=598) очень много плагинов, которые умеют это делать ([**подборка для JQuery**](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/)).

В простейшем же случае валидация выглядит приблизительно так:

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Необходимо заполнить поле Имя!");
  return false;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="action.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Имя: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ооо спасибо !!!

Comment: А подскажите, если у меня условие еще одно есть, поля всегда должно быть равно 10, т.е. если поле равно 10 тогда данные отправляем, если все остальное ну там "пусто", "null", "любой символ" тогда выводим сообщение что "Укажите верное значение!"

Comment: Все решил!
 function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["form"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == 10) {
  return true;
  } else {
   alert("Необходимо указать верный результат уравнения!");
   return false;
  }
 }